# How to run Nginx on multiple ports

Tags: nginx

I am trying to configure nginx on two ports with the same instance, for example on port 80 and port 81, but no luck so far. Here is an example of what I am trying to do:

```
worker_processes  1;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    sendfile        on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    server {
        listen  80;
        server_name  chat.local.com;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_buffering off;

        }
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }

    }

    server {
        listen  81;
        server_name  console.local.com;
        location / {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8888;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_buffering off;
        }
    }
}
```

When I try to run console.local.com, it shows the content from chat.local.com. Is there a way to make nginx run on two ports? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

your config looks ok

I think the problem is this (correct me if I'm wrong):

- you have console.local.com listening on port 81,
- that means you need to access it as http://console.local.com:81/
- when you access it as http://console.local.com/  (no explicit port so defaults to port 80)
  nginx will check, notice that noting is listening on port 80 for that server_name, and consequently will pass the request to the default server-block. Since the defaut server-block is the first one (in the absence of configuration to change it) you end up in the chat.local.com handling.

In all likelyhood you want to change your console.local.com to listen on port 80 also since:

- the server_name directive in both serverblocks is enough to differentiate the requests
- that avoids you having to add the :81 to the domainname in the requests all the time

Comment: Hi Cobaco, I totally forgot the point that I would need to access the page with port 81. Thanks for pointing out that point.

Answer (score 6):

You can add listen statement 2 times simple; like below

listen 80;

listen 81;

This should work with nginx